# Can I get page token from youtube api using xml?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on youtube api and developing a youtube api website and I want to get next page token for videos list, but I am getting data from xml feed.

How can I get next page token from xml feed?

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
// set feed URL
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed';

// read feed into SimpleXML object
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
?>
<h1><?php echo $sxml->title; ?></h1>
<?php
// iterate over entries in feed
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
  // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
  $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

  // get video player URL
  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
  $watch = $attrs['url']; 

  // get video thumbnail
  $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
  $thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 

  // get <yt:duration> node for video length
  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
  $length = $attrs['seconds']; 

  // get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics
  $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
  $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount']; 

  // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
  $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
  if ($gd->rating) {
    $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
    $rating = $attrs['average']; 
  } else {
    $rating = 0; 
  }
  $my_format = 'mqdefault.jpg'; 
  $my_url = 'img.ytapi.com';
  ?>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="title">
      <a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>"><?php echo $media->group->title; ?></a>
    </span>
    <p>
      <span class="thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>"><img src="<?php echo str_replace(array("i.ytimg.com","0.jpg"),array($my_url, $my_format), $thumbnail);?>" /></a>
        <br/>click to view
      </span> 
      <span class="attr">By:</span> <?php echo $entry->author->name; ?> <br/>
      <span class="attr">Duration:</span> <?php printf('%0.2f', $length/60); ?> 
      min. <br/>
      <span class="attr">Views:</span> <?php echo $viewCount; ?> <br/>
      <span class="attr">Rating:</span> <?php echo $rating; ?> 
    </p>
  </div>      
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request additional pages using the [`start-index`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#start-indexsp) parameter. This parameter works in conjunction with [`max-results`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#max-resultssp) parameter. So:

If you omit the `max-results` parameter then request these URLs:

- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed
  Results 1-25
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed?start-index=26
  Results 26-50
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed?start-index=51
  Results 51-75

If you set `max-results=10` then request these URLs:

- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed?max-results=10
  Results 1-10
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed?max-results=10&start-index=11
  Results 11-20
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed?max-results=10&start-index=21
  Results 21-30